# Configuring WSO2 API Manager to use the WSO2 BAM Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Using WSO2 API Manager 1.3 and WSO2 BAM 2.0.

I followed the instructions found in the README.txt in /statistics.

I am getting the following error when starting API Manager:

> TID: [0] [AM] [2013-05-02 11:42:44,239] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher}
>   -  Error initializing APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher}
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException:
>   Error when finding event stream definition for :
>   org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request 1.0.0

Any suggestions on where to start looking for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not properly configured WSO2 API Manager 1.3 to work with WSO2 BAM.
For proper configuration follow the official docs[1]

This issue might also occur When you set an offset to BAM by 1 as described in the README.txt, as it needs its Cassandra DB configurations to be changed for the offset by 1 at BAM_HOME/repository/conf/etc/cassandra-component.xml. Therefore follow the like provided[1] where we change the API Manager's offset.

Suho

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Monitoring+and+Statistics