# Unable to view statics in the WSO2 API Manager Publisher?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I'm setting up WSO2 API Manager & WSO2 BAM. I folloed each and every step given in the below article.

http://umeshagunasinghe.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-configure-wso2-api-manager-to.html

I see below error in the terminal when I try to access the statistics page.

```
[2015-02-06 14:15:29,405] ERROR - usage:jag java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Below is the page I get. 
[image]

I checked below questions as well. but didn't work out for me.

[Why am I unable to view stats in the WSO2 API Manager Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765135/why-am-i-unable-to-view-stats-in-the-wso2-api-manager-store)

[Configuring WSO2 API Manager to use the WSO2 BAM Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343805/configuring-wso2-api-manager-to-use-the-wso2-bam-server)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to start WSO2 BAM first. It should create the relavent tables.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing as mentioned in the guide. If possible please post the steps to be carried out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this error because there are no data to be shown. Please invoke APIs and try this page.

*Please read the comments for more info*

Comment: shows this error : [2015-02-09 14:28:06,896]  WARN {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Downed localhost(127.0.0.1):9162 host still appears to be down: Unable to open transport to localhost(127.0.0.1):9162 , java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: Change $BAM_HOME/repository/conf/etc/hector-config.xml as follows

Comment: What's the port number should I use?

Comment: <nodes>localhost:9161</nodes>

Comment: & why does the port is shown as 9162 in the error log instead of 9161 as per the configuration

Comment: Here is a post I posted recently which will help you to integrate BAM and API Manager. You can use it since Umesha's post may not work with newer versions. http://emsooriyabandara.blogspot.com/2014/10/integrating-wso2-api-manager-with-bam.html

Comment: if I skip CEP steps this is exactly same as Umesha's post.

Comment: Plus I don't use mysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70587/discussion-between-eranda-and-techie).