# Downed localhost(127.0.0.1):9162 host still appears to be down

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I'm setting up WSO2 API Manager & WSO2 BAM. I folloed each and every step given in the below article.

http://umeshagunasinghe.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-configure-wso2-api-manager-to.html

I see below error in the terminal when I try to access the statistics page.

```
[2015-02-09 15:04:17,418]  WARN {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Downed localhost(127.0.0.1):9162 host still appears to be down: Unable to open transport to localhost(127.0.0.1):9162 , java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

    <providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>

    <datasources>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>


<datasource>
          <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
          <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
   <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
          <definition type="RDBMS">
          <configuration>
                 <!-- JDBC URL to query the database -->
                 <url>jdbc:h2:/opt/wso2bam-2.4.1/repository/database/APIMGTSTATS_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
                 <username>wso2carbon</username>
                 <password>wso2carbon</password>
                 <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                 <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                 <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                 <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                 <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                 <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
         </definition>
  </datasource>


       <datasource>
           <name>WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE</name>
           <description>The datasource used for Cassandra data</description>
           <definition type="RDBMS">
               <configuration>
                   <url>jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9161/EVENT_KS</url>
                   <username>admin</username>
                   <password>admin</password>
               </configuration>
           </definition>
       </datasource>


     <datasource>
            <name>WSO2BAM_UTIL_DATASOURCE</name>
            <description>The datasource used for BAM utilities, such as message store etc..</description>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9161/BAM_UTIL_KS</url>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

                <!-- For an explanation of the properties, see: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html -->
        <!--datasource>
            <name>SAMPLE_DATA_SOURCE</name>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name></name>
                <environment>
                    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial"></property>
                    <property name="java.naming.provider.url"></property>
                </environment>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>

                    <defaultAutoCommit></defaultAutoCommit>
                    <defaultReadOnly></defaultReadOnly>
                    <defaultTransactionIsolation>NONE|READ_COMMITTED|READ_UNCOMMITTED|REPEATABLE_READ|SERIALIZABLE</defaultTransactionIsolation>
                    <defaultCatalog></defaultCatalog>
                    <username></username>
                    <password svns:secretAlias="WSO2.DB.Password"></password>
                    <maxActive></maxActive>
                    <maxIdle></maxIdle>
                    <initialSize></initialSize>
                    <maxWait></maxWait>

                    <dataSourceClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</dataSourceClassName>
                    <dataSourceProps>
                        <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test1</property>
                        <property name="user">root</property>
                        <property name="password">123</property>
                    </dataSourceProps>

                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource-->

    </datasources>

</datasources-configuration>
```

Offset is set as below as mentioned in the guide

```
<Offset>1</Offset>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Here's something.  The config files you have shown us are using 9161 as the port number, yet the error message says 9162.  (And the docs in @dumiduh's answer say to use 9163 as the port number!!!)  Are you are using the right port number in all of the right places?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. because only thing I did is following the guide

Comment: What is the BAM version you are using? Is it 2.3.0 or 2.4.1?

Comment: I'm using wso2bam-2.4.1

Comment: @Eranda Please refer this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362981/unable-to-view-statics-in-the-wso2-api-manager-publisher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the documentation might be incorrect for BAM 2.4 (I'm running BAM 2.5.0) and upwards when working with port offsets. I followed the documentation at first to discover that my logs kept trying to connect to a cassandra port that wasn't valid in my config. I used an offset of 1, which would have made the port 9161. In my BAM logs I kept seeing messages that it was trying to connect to port 9162. I reverted the /repository/conf/etc/hector-config.xml change back to its default port and everything came up fine.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

So it seems in BAM 2.4.0 and above that the code takes in account the port offset. I was able to get BAM running correctly by ommitting step 5 in the above documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this doc if you are using APIM 1.7. I tried this a while back and it works.

[Publishing API Runtime Statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics)

Comment: I tried this it does not work. That's why I used the above mentioned article

Comment: there are multiple errors in the guide with regard to cassandra port IMO. if you want to run BAM with an offset,  change all references to cassandra port accordingly. check in hector-config, datasources and api-manager.

Comment: You can refer http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70587/discussion-between-eranda-and-techie

Answer (score 0):

What are the relevant API-M and BAM versions you are using? The above article is only relevant to that particular versions of API-M and BAM as mentioned in the blog. Configurations are different for the latest versions. Please refer following [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics) for the latest BAM and API-M integration steps.